How do I reference an outside cell in a query?
For budgeting, I'd like to be able to know how much money was due before the next paycheck. I was able to figure out the paycheck date formula, but I'm having an issue with the query. It looks like it is referencing the correct cell, but it is giving me an #ERROR still. Any help would be appreciated.
=QUERY(G2:H14,"select sum(G) where H<"B16"")

Here is a link to a sample sheet. I'm specifically looking for the formula that would go in G17.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14PMWNXfHIpEhoQD_xJ52s4exhN7Xd_ke5yPGxuTFLyQ/edit?usp=sharing

You are trying to compare a numeric value (amount) to a date? B16 is a date and SUM implies a numeric value. Also, H column is also a date not a numerical value. I am confused why are you are including that in the query?

I want to compare the dates in the due date column against B16. If it is sooner than the paydate, I want to sum the adjacent values (in H).

You can use dates with QUERY, but it's tricky. I suggest to use SUMIF:
=SUMIF(H2:H14,">"&B16,G2:G14)



You can try this formula for your desired output
Formula:
=QUERY(G2:H14, "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE H < date '"&TEXT(B16, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label SUM(G) ''", 0)

Output:

References:
Query function
Query with dates
